# What's a shorter way of writing `(\ x -> traceShow x x )`?

Tags: debugging, haskell

Printing the value of an expression is a common practice in debugging. For example, if I have a piece of code like this

```hs
my . super . cool . fUnCtIoN . chain $ value
```

and I am trying to see the output of `fUnCtIoN . chain`, I would add

```hs
my . super . cool . (\ x -> traceShow x x ) . fUnCtIoN . chain $ value
```

which is mouthful for a simple task like this, not to mention if I want to print many intermediate results:

```hs
(\ x -> traceShow x x )
    . my
    . (\ x -> traceShow x x )
    . super
    . (\ x -> traceShow x x )
    . cool
    . (\ x -> traceShow x x )
    . fUnCtIoN
    . (\ x -> traceShow x x )
    . chain
    $ value
```

It would just look awful. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [`traceShowId`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShowId)! It does exactly what you're asking for.

```
my . super . cool . traceShowId . fUnCtIoN . chain $ value
```

Comment: Is there a function that does `(\ x -> trace msg x )`? The function `traceId` is oddly returning `msg` itself. Why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: I asked the above question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059378/why-does-traceid-return-the-message-string-itself).

Comment: @trVoldemort You can eta reduce that to `(trace msg)`

Answer (score 4):

Yes. `join traceShow`.

```
λ>  import Control.Monad
λ> :t join
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
λ> :t join (+)
join (+) :: Num a => a -> a
```

In the case of the function monad, `join f x = f x x`, so `join traceShow` is equivalent to `\x -> traceShow x x`.

Or make a `where` clause that provides a new definition of `(.)`:

```
--...your code without the nasty bits...
    where
       (.) f g a = f ( join traceShow (g a))
```

Which may just help, though there will be one more `traceShow` call than previously.

Comment: That's an interesting way of doing it. I didn't know I could use `join` this way.

Comment: @trVoldemort Yup. It's surprising how often we forget that the function is indeed a monad.

Answer (score 2):

How about a helper function for adding a trace call to a function:

```hs
dbg :: Show a => String -> a -> a
dbg name x = trace (name ++ ": " ++ show x) x

main = do
  let x = dbg "my"    . my
        . dbg "super" . super
        . dbg "cool"  . cool
        . dbg "func"  . fUnCtIoN
        . dbg "chain" . chain
        $ value
  print x

my       = (+1)
super    = (+2)
cool     = (+3)
fUnCtIoN = (+4)
chain    = (+5)
value = 3
```

Output:

```hs
chain: 3
func: 8
cool: 12
super: 15
my: 17
18
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a higher-order function which takes a function of two arguments and uses the same value for both arguments.

```
applyBoth :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> b
applyBoth f x = f x x
```

(Aside: this is `join` for the "reader" monad `(->) a`.)

Then you can use that combinator in curried form:

```
applyBoth traceShow
    . my
    . applyBoth traceShow
    . super
    . applyBoth traceShow
    . cool
    . applyBoth traceShow
    . fUnCtIoN
    . applyBoth traceShow
    . chain
    $ value
```

Or define an alias for `applyBoth traceShow`.

```
traceS = applyBoth traceShow

traceS
    . my
    . traceS
    . super
    . traceS
    . cool
    . traceS
    . fUnCtIoN
    . traceS
    . chain
    $ value
```

For maximum terseness points, you can automatically interleave `traceS` into a list of functions by folding it up:

```
showSteps :: Show a => [a -> a] -> a -> a
showSteps = foldr (\f g -> f . traceS . g) id

showSteps [my, super, cool, fUnCtIoN, chain] value
```

---

**Edit** Eh, what the hell... It's not entirely relevant, but here's how to make `showSteps` work when you want to pipeline your data through a number of types. It's an example of a program we wouldn't be able to write without GHC's advanced type system features (`GADTs` and `RankNTypes` in this instance).

`Path` is a GADT which explains how to walk through a directed graph of types, starting at the source type `x` and ending at the destination type `y`. It's parameterised by a category `c :: * -> * -> *`.

```
infixr 6 :->
data Path c x y where
    End :: Path c z z
    (:->) :: c x y -> Path c y z -> Path c x z
```

`:->` reminds us that a journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step: if the category you're working in lets you go from `x` to `y`, and you can take a path from `y` to `z`, you can go from `x` to `z`.
`End` is for when you have reached your destination - it's pretty easy to walk from `z` to `z` by not walking at all.

So `Path` has the same recursive structure as a linked list, but with a more flexible approach to the things inside it. Rather than requiring all of its elements to have the same type, it gives you a way to join up arrows like dominos, as long as the return type of one arrow matches the input type of the next. (To use the mathematical jargon: if you view the underlying category `c` as a logical relation, then [`End` augments `c` with reflexivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_closure) and [`:->` augments `c` with transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#Existence_and_description). `Path c` thus constructs the *reflexive transitive closure* of `c`. Another way of looking at this is that `Path` is the *free category*, much like `[]` is the *free monoid*; you can define `instance Category (Path c)` without any constraint on `c`.)

You can fold up a `Path` with exactly the same code as you use to fold up a list, but the type is more precise: the folding function can't know anything *a priori* about the types of the arrows inside the path.

```
foldr :: (forall x y. c x y -> r y z -> r x z) -> r z z -> Path c x z -> r x z
foldr f z End = z
foldr f z (x :-> xs) = f x $ foldr f z xs
```

At this point, I could define type-aligned sequences of functions (`type TAS = Path (->)`) and show you how `f :-> g :-> h :-> End` can be folded up into `h . g . f`, but since our goal is to print out all the intermediate values, we have to use a category with a tiny bit more structure than plain old `->`. (Thanks to @dfeuer in the comments for the suggestion - I've adjusted the name he gave to better reflect the attention-seeking nature of my behaviour.)

```
data Showoff x y where
    Showoff :: Show y => (x -> y) -> Showoff x y
```

`Showoff` is just like a regular function, except it assures you that the return value `y` will be `Show`able. We can use this extra bit of knowledge to write `showSteps` for paths in which each step is a `Showoff`.

```
type ShowTAS = Path Showoff

showSteps :: ShowTAS a b -> a -> b
showSteps path = foldr combine id path . traceS
    where combine (Showoff f) g = g . traceS . f
```

It strikes me as a bit of a shame to use the *impure* `traceS` right in the midst of all this strongly typed fun. In real life I'd probably return a `String` along with the answer.

To prove that it does actually work, here is a chain of functions with varying types. We take in a `String`, `read` it into an `Int`, add one to it, convert it to a `Float`, then divide it by 2.

```
chain :: ShowTAS String Float
chain = Showoff read :-> plusOne :-> toFloat :-> divideTwo :-> End

    where plusOne :: Showoff Int Int
          plusOne = Showoff (+1)

          toFloat :: Showoff Int Float
          toFloat = Showoff fromIntegral

          divideTwo :: Showoff Float Float
          divideTwo = Showoff (/2)

ghci> showSteps chain "4"
"4"
4
5
5.0
2.5
2.5  -- this last one is not from a traceShow call, it's just ghci printing the result
```

Fun!

Comment: What, you're not going to generalize from lists of endomorphisms to type-aligned sequences of morphisms???

Comment: @dfeuer I almost did - I had a GADT called `Path` all ready to go - but then I realised it was rather an excessive answer to the question :P. (Also, I don't know of a clean way to enforce `Show`ability for all the intermediate types of a TAS without shoving the constraint into the GADT itself.)

Comment: You can force the arrow type to cough up instances, I suppose. `data Showorph x y where Showorph :: (Show x, Show y) => (x -> y) -> Showorph x y`

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for the suggestion! I ended up sticking it in my answer after all.

Comment: `Showoff` is a great name. I was trying to suggest "shawarma" in the great Haskell sandwich tradition. My double-sided constraint was a cop-out: I didn't want to have to think about which end should be `Show`. Glad you worked that out.

Comment: I noticed you mentioned `Path` is parameterized by a category, which is often true. But this is not generally the case, and doesn't seem to be the case in the rest of the discussion. `Path c` is a category *no matter what `c` is*.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, that's what I was trying to get at with my comment about `Path c` being `c`'s reflexive transitive closure. I guess I didn't do a good job of explaining that. I used the word "category" to emphasise the fact that in this example we're using `Path` as a sequence of morphisms