# Why does `traceId` return the message string itself?

Tags: debugging, haskell

I found it really weird that [`traceId`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceId) returns the message string itself. Why would anyone want to do that?

Is there a common scenario where `traceId` would come in handy?

Comment: `traceMsg = trace`...

Comment: @ErikAllik: Sorry I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

Credits to David who drew attention on the fact that my `traceId'` is exactly `traceShowId`.

Hence, `traecId` is simply the `String -> String` monomorphic version of the polymorphic `traceShowId :: Show a -> a -> a`, which also strips the printed string from quotes.

**Old answer:**

One way to interpret `traceId` is that it's a `String`-specialized version of a more general `traceId'` which is not in the stdlib:

```hs
traceId' :: Show a => a -> a
traceId' x = trace (show x) x
```

so that

```hs
traceId = traceId' :: String -> String
```

**Example:**

```hs
my = id; func = id; chain = id; value = 3

main = do
  print $ length $ traceId "chain is called!"
  print $ length $ traceId' [1,2,3]
```

but for some reason the general version of `traceId`, which I've called `traceId'`, is not in the stdlib.

Comment: Hummm ... interesting view. (BTW technically `traceId'` is not exactly `traceId` in the `String` case, as `traceId` uses `id` instead of `show`, which means the string is unescaped and unquoted when printed)

Comment: I guess the reason is more of a consistency consideration. `traceId` should be exactly as its name indicated -- `trace` with its first argument identical to its second.

Comment: actually I'm curious if somebody can give a better explanation about `traceId` — like why it's not `Show a => a -> a` in the first place.

Comment: I think `traceId'` is `traceShowId`, which is in `Debug.Trace`

Comment: Also, `traceId'`/`traceShowId` would have double quotes while `traceId` (I suspect) would not. Haven't tried it though.