# Apply the composition of a list of functions to each number of a list

Tags: haskell, function-composition

Given a list of functions and a list of numbers, I want first function to be applied to a list of numbers, the result then used for second function, and so on.

```
wantedFunc [(*2), (+2), (/2)] [1,2,3,4]
              |     |     |
              |     |     |
              V     |     |
        [2,4,6,8]---|     |
                    |     |
                    V     |
             [4,6,8,10]---|
                          V 
                      [2,3,4,5] -- End result
```

Is there a build-in function for this?

Comment: Show your best attempt so far.

Comment: I really don't have any elegant solution for this. I take each function and fmap them one by one.

Comment: Provocative question: what do you do when the functions in your list aren't all the same type? Provocative answer: you do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33058994/1523776)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying directly your definition we get

```
wantedFunc :: [(a -> a)] -> [a] -> [a]
wantedFunc fs xs = foldl (\ys f -> map f ys) xs fs
```

but we can transform

```
foldl (\ys f -> map f ys) xs fs
foldl (\ys f -> flip map ys f) xs fs    -- flip map
foldl (flip map) xs fs                  -- remove lambda
flip (foldl (flip map)) fs xs           -- flip foldl
flip (foldl (flip map))                 -- remove lambda
flip $ foldl $ flip map                 -- or using ($)
```

and finally

```
wantedFunc :: [(a -> a)] -> [a] -> [a]
wantedFunc = flip $ foldl $ flip map
```

on the other hand we can change the function signature flipping arguments and the functions list order and we can write that function as

```
wantedFunc' :: [a] -> [(a -> a)] -> [a]
wantedFunc' = foldr map
```

e.g.

```
main = do
    print $ wantedFunc  [(*2), (+2), (/2)] [1,2,3,4]
    print $ wantedFunc' [1,2,3,4] [(/2), (+2), (*2)]
```

with output

```
[2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
[2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

Comment: That's neat. I flip the arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```hs
import Control.Arrow ((>>>))

wantedFunc :: Foldable t => t (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
wantedFunc fs = map f
  where
    f = compose fs
    compose = foldr (>>>) id
```

does the trick:

```hs
λ> wantedFunc [(*2), (+2), (/2)] [1, 2, 3, 4]
[2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

Comment: Or `flip (foldl $ flip map)`

Comment: @josejuan, I ended up using your answer. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

A right fold solution would be:

```
fun :: (Functor f, Foldable t) => t (a -> a) -> f a -> f a
fun = foldr (\f -> (. fmap f)) id
```

then,

```
\> fun [(*2), (+2)] [1,2,3,4]
[4,6,8,10]

\> fun [(*2), (+2), (`div` 2)] [1,2,3,4]
[2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `fmap fmap` approach, using a Monoid to compose the functions.

```
newtype Endo a = Endo { unwrap :: a -> a }

instance Monoid (Endo a) where
  mempty = Endo id
  mappend (Endo f) (Endo g) = Endo (g . f)

wantedFunc = unwrap . mconcat . fmap (Endo . fmap)

λ wantedFunc [(*2), (+2), (/2)] [1,2,3,4]
[2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

a one-liner solution can be

```
> map (foldr (.) id $ reverse [(*2),(+2),(/2)]) [1..4]
[2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just compose all the functions and apply map.

```
wantedFunc :: [a->a] -> [a] -> [a]
wantedFunc fs = map (foldl1 (.) fs)
```